# How do I create an xmlElement from the current node of a xmlReader?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

If I have an xmlreader instance how can I use it to read its current node and end up with a xmlElement instance?

Comment: Do you really want XmlElement, and not XElement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not tested, but how about via an `XmlDocument`:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(reader);
    XmlElement el = doc.DocumentElement;
```

Alternatively (from the cmoment), something like:

```
    doc.LoadXml(reader.ReadOuterXml());
```

But actually I'm not a fan of that... it forces an additional xml-parse step (one of the more CPU-expensive operations) for no good reason. If the original is being glitchy, then perhaps consider a sub-reader:

```
    using (XmlReader subReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(subReader);
        XmlElement el = doc.DocumentElement;
    }
```

Comment: change line 2 to doc.LoadXml(reader.ReadOuterXml()); so I can accept. Thanks.

Comment: How this answers the question? This will read the whole xml into XmlDocument, and will return the root element only.

Comment: @Sunny; the root element contains all other elements as descendants

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have XmlDocument, where you need to attach the newly created XmlElement:

```
XmlElement myElement;
myXmlReader.Read();
if (myXmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
{
   myElement = doc.CreateElement(myXmlReader.Name);
   myElement.InnerXml = myXmlReader.InnerXml;
}
```

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.xmlelement.aspx): Do not instantiate an XmlElement directly; instead, use methods such as CreateElement.